# How to unify a Eventhandler call onto two stacked JComponents

Tags: java, swing, events, javafx

Problem: I have a JButton with a Icon and a RolloverIcon(Hover effect), to this I added a via add()
a JFXPanel containing the String written onto that JButton. How can I properly forward the Rollover to the JFXPanel? Because at the moment Im calling setOnMouseEntered in the JFXPanel to alter the background of the JButton, but the transition from the Rollover JButton event is not seamless to the inner JFXPanel setOnMouseEntered.

More precise explanation: As soon as I hover with the mouse from the wrapper JButton onto the inner JFXPanel the Rollover of the JButton tries to revert the Icon on the button to the non-rollover version. But at the same time the the newly called setOnMouseEntered tries to set the JButton Icon to the Rollover version. Resulting in visual Racecondition or simply stuttering.

I packed the resources and src files into this [Zip-File](http://georodin.de/index.php/s/DYSTNFmaNEB5pCw)

[I also have mini-video for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqqNd.jpg)

What I had in mind as resolutions:

- is there a way to make the JFXPanel completely click through so I only need the Rollover of the parent Button
- maybe render within the JButton-Class the JFXPanel into the Icon or Images so I can purely rely on the rollover effect

Main-Class:

```
package main.testbench;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class MainStarter implements UrlGetter{
    
    static final double MULTI = 2.0;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) (400*MULTI),(int) (400*MULTI)));
                frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension((int) (400*MULTI),(int) (400*MULTI)));
                frame.setVisible(true);  
                
                JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
                pnl.setBackground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
                
                pnl.add(new ButtonIconHover("Reisen", "test", new Dimension((int) (110*MULTI),(int) (40*MULTI))));
                
                frame.add(pnl);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

JButton-Class:

```
public class ButtonIconHover extends JButton implements UrlGetter {

    public ButtonIconHover(String display, String action, Dimension dimension) {
        super();

        super.setOpaque(false);
        super.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        super.setBorderPainted(false);  
        super.setPreferredSize(dimension);
        super.setMinimumSize(dimension);

        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(getURL("resources/Button.jpg"));
        ImageIcon imageIconHover = new ImageIcon(getURL("resources/Button_h.jpg"));
        
        Image image = imageIcon.getImage();
        Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(dimension.width, dimension.height,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 
        imageIcon = new ImageIcon(newimg);
        
        Image imageHover = imageIconHover.getImage();
        Image newimgHover = imageHover.getScaledInstance(dimension.width, dimension.height,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 
        imageIconHover = new ImageIcon(newimgHover);
        
        super.setIcon(imageIcon);
        super.setRolloverIcon(imageIconHover);
        super.setPressedIcon(imageIconHover);
        super.setActionCommand(action);
        
        add(new FXButtonFont(display, dimension, this));
    }
}
```

JFXPanel-Class:

```
package main.testbench;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.Icon;

import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.effect.Light;
import javafx.scene.effect.Lighting;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
 
public class FXButtonFont extends JFXPanel implements UrlGetter{
    public FXButtonFont(String display, Dimension dimension, ButtonIconHover buttonIconHover) {
        super();
        Light.Distant light = new Light.Distant();
        light.setAzimuth(-45.0);

        Lighting lighting = new Lighting();
        lighting.setLight(light);
        lighting.setSurfaceScale(1.5*MainStarter.MULTI);
        lighting.setSpecularConstant(2.0);
        lighting.setSpecularExponent(10.0);

        Text text = new Text(0 ,0, display);
//        text.setText(display);
        text.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        Font font = Font.loadFont(getURL("resources/fonts/Arson-Regular.ttf").toString(), 20*MainStarter.MULTI);
        text.setFont(font);

        
        DropShadow shadow = new DropShadow();
        shadow.setSpread(0);
        shadow.setColor(Color.web("0x000000", 0.7));
        shadow.setOffsetX(-2);
        shadow.setOffsetY(2);
        shadow.setWidth(4);
        shadow.setRadius(4);
        shadow.setInput(lighting);
        text.setEffect(shadow);
        
        Icon imageIcon = buttonIconHover.getIcon();
        Icon imageIconHover = buttonIconHover.getRolloverIcon();
        
          text.setOnMouseEntered((event) -> {
              buttonIconHover.setIcon(imageIconHover);
          });
          
          text.setOnMouseExited((event) -> {
              buttonIconHover.setIcon(imageIcon);
          });
        
      //Setting the stage
      StackPane root = new StackPane();
      StackPane.setAlignment(text, Pos.CENTER);
      StackPane.setMargin(text, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
      root.getChildren().add(text);
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, dimension.getWidth(),dimension.getHeight(), Color.TRANSPARENT);
      setPreferredSize(dimension);
      setMinimumSize(dimension);
      this.setScene(scene);
    }
}
```

UrlGetter-Interface:

```
package main.testbench;

import java.net.URL;

public interface UrlGetter {
    public default URL getURL(String resource) {
        return getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(resource);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine a Icon on a Swing JButton seamless with a JavaFX Text I did the following:

1. Load both Icon and RolloverIcon onto the `JButton` so that the Image is already loaded
2. because awt `Image`s are asynchronous and need to be loaded to be altered
3. Create a `FXButtonFont`(extends FXJPanel) object within the `ButtonIconHover`(extends JButton) constructor
4. all following calls are made within a nested `Platform.runLater` because we will need the JavaFX Thread
5. call on the JFXPanel `getScene` and on the Scene `snapshot(WritableImage)`
6. use `SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(WritableImage, null)` to convert the `WritableImage` to `BufferedImage`
7. then call a self written `mergeImages` wich combines two `BufferedImages` into one
8. now set the returned `BufferedImage` as `setIcon` to the `JButton`

Here the modified ButtonIconHover:

```
public ButtonIconHover(String display, String action, Dimension dimension) {
    super();

    super.setOpaque(false);
    super.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    super.setBorderPainted(false);  
    super.setPreferredSize(dimension);
    super.setMinimumSize(dimension);

    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(getURL("resources/Button.jpg"));
    ImageIcon imageIconHover = new ImageIcon(getURL("resources/Button_h.jpg"));
    
    Image image = imageIcon.getImage();
    Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(dimension.width, dimension.height,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 
    
    Image imageHover = imageIconHover.getImage();
    Image newimgHover = imageHover.getScaledInstance(dimension.width, dimension.height,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 

    super.setIcon(new ImageIcon(newimg));
    super.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(newimgHover));
    FXButtonFont FXBtnString = new FXButtonFont(display, dimension, false);
    FXButtonFont FXBtnStringHover = new FXButtonFont(display, dimension, true);
    ButtonIconHover thisbtn = this;
    
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            WritableImage img = new WritableImage((int)dimension.getWidth(), (int)dimension.getHeight()) ;
            WritableImage imgHover = new WritableImage((int)dimension.getWidth(), (int)dimension.getHeight()) ;
            FXBtnString.getScene().snapshot(img);
            FXBtnStringHover.getScene().snapshot(imgHover);
            
            BufferedImage FXBtnStringConverted = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(img, null);
            BufferedImage FXBtnStringConvertedHover = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(imgHover, null);
            
            BufferedImage combined = ImageUtil.mergeImages(ImageUtil.convertToBufferedImage(newimg), FXBtnStringConverted);
            BufferedImage combinedRollPress = ImageUtil.mergeImages(ImageUtil.convertToBufferedImage(newimgHover), FXBtnStringConvertedHover);

            ImageIcon nonConverted = new ImageIcon(combined);
            ImageIcon rollPress = new ImageIcon(combinedRollPress);
            thisbtn.setIcon(nonConverted);
            thisbtn.setRolloverIcon(rollPress);
            thisbtn.setPressedIcon(rollPress);
        }
    });  
    
}
```